# How do I append null to a ByteArray?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am writing a stream that needs to be aligned to a particular size.  What is the right way of appending null (or any value) without exposing sensitive areas of RAM outside Array.Copy?

For example, I need to "round up" `byteArray.Length` to the value of pad:

```
 byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(preStream);
 long pad = (minBlobEntrySize * databaseCount) - byteArray.Length;
 Array.Copy(byteArray, 0, buffer, relativeOffset2, byteArray.Length);
```

And I know that the following is wrong since it may expose sensitive data:

```
  Array.Copy(byteArray, 0, buffer, relativeOffset2, byteArray.Length + pad);
```

What is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: I'm confused... What do RAM and pointers have to do with this? You may need to show us some code to illustrate your issue.

Comment: did you try to check the length of the stream, and on flush to just write 0 bytes until it's aligned?

Comment: C# is managed. You won't expose sensitive data. You will maybe get exception because of array capacity, but you won't expose sensitive data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `Array.Resize` method should do what you want here.

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(preStream);
long pad = (minBlobEntrySize * databaseCount) - byteArray.Length;
Array.Resize(ref byteArray, byteArray.Length + pad);
Array.Copy(byteArray, 0, buffer, relativeOffset2, byteArray.Length);
```

Note that you don't need the `+ pad` in the `Copy` method as the length will be the resized one.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays of value types in C# are [automatically initialized to all zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx) (I know the documentation I linked to say "numeric" types, but it means value types). If this is a fresh array, you don't have to do anything special. In this case, that means always declaring your array with the proper size, and copying the stream to it:

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(preStream);
byte[] byteArray = new byte[Math.Min(minBlobEntrySize * databaseCount, buffer.Length)]; 
Array.Copy(buffer, byteArray, buffer.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[byteArray.Length + pad];
```

is this what you're looking for? Other bytes will be zero.

### Edit

If you're using buffer for previous values (as I would presume based on the relativeOffset2 value), you could do this maybe:

```
 byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(preStream);
 long pad = (minBlobEntrySize * databaseCount) - byteArray.Length;
 Array.Copy(byteArray, 0, buffer, relativeOffset2, byteArray.Length);

 byte[] padBuff = new byte[pad]; //will be zeros...
 Array.Copy(padBuff, 0, buffer, relativeOffset2 + byteArray.Length, pad);
```

or you could just use a

```
for(int i=0; i< pad; i++)
    buffer[relativeOffset2 + byteArray.Length + i] = 0;
```

I presume your buffer is of sufficient size ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by exposing sensitive data, but I would just write to the stream directly.

```
long alignedLength = minBlobEntrySize * databaseCount;
while (stream.Length < alignedLength)
{
    stream.WriteByte(0);
}
```